# Excel: Combining SIN function array and RAND to add noise

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formula, trigonometry

As the title suggests, I would like to combine SIN function with RAND function so that it results in an imperfect SIN trend. As of right now I've got two functions:

SIN function:

```
=TRANSPOSE((SIN(RADIANS(ROW(INDIRECT("1:31"))*15))+1))
```

RAND function:

```
=RAND()
```

As you can see, the SIN function stems from an array that is 31 cells wide. Yet I am not sure how to combine it with RAND function so that the RAND factor would apply each of these cells individually, rather than just shifting / multiplying the whole array.

This is the current state of my data:

[image]

Is there a way to combine the two in one single function?

On a slightly different note, is there a way to "freeze" RAND function so that it wouldn't update after every action? (without copy pasting it as value)

Comment: just add them: `=TRANSPOSE((SIN(RADIANS(ROW(INDIRECT("1:31"))*15))+1))+RAND()`  As to making it "Stop", no there is no way with formula.  Your best bet is to create a vba routine that fills the data like you want and have a button or shortcut to refill when wanted.

Comment: Not the case here, since it adds the same rand value to the whole array, while I'd like to have it random for each of the cells within an array

Comment: You are correct.  My mistake.  But the rest of the comment fits.  Rand and Indirect are volatile and will recalc with any change any where on any open workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Randarray, where you specify 1 row and 31 columns. Formula represented in row 3...

```
=TRANSPOSE((SIN(RADIANS(ROW(INDIRECT("1:31"))*15))+1))+RANDARRAY(1,31)
```

[image]